# pip install with wipe option by default

Tags: python, pip

In a python (django) project, when I change the location of an existing dependency with pip, and I reinstall the updated requirements.txt file in another machine, I am being prompted with a message like this:-

```
Obtaining South from git+git://github.com/lambdafu/django-south.git@7bb081348d854d0b1aa82b87da5b446ad5d6f2a6#egg=South-dev (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  git clone in ./src/south exists with URL git://github.com/clones/django-south.git
  The plan is to install the git repository git://github.com/lambdafu/django-south.git
What to do?  (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup
```

At this point, I will select "w" (wipe) to wipe out the old copy of django-south and use django-south from the new repository location.

I would like to do this as a default behavior without needing to type "w".

Is there an option I can specify when giving my

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

command so that the installation process will automatically know that I want to wipe out the older copy and will not prompt me to choose s/i/w/b ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the `yes` command:

```
yes w | pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Saying 'w' blindly to any input seems pretty dangerous to me.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14644866/237091 is much safer.

Answer (score 31):

From PIP version 1.1 onwards you can also use:

--exists-action=EXISTS_ACTION
                        Default action when a path already exists.Use this
                        option more then one time to specify another action if
                        a certain option is not available, choices: (s)witch,
                        (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup